# Catching error exceptions in Laravel 4

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel

From the documentation it says we can catch all 404 like so:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

And we can also do things like:

```
App::abort(404);
App::abort(403);
```

All 404 gets handled by the `App::missing`

All other errors gets handled by:

```
App::error(function( HttpException $e)
{
    //handle the error
});
```

But the question is `How do i handle each of the error like if its a 403 I will display this if its a 400 I will display another error`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: if your custom App::error function does not return a value, Laravel will handle it. [Check the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-errors)

Code sample for custom error views and/or logic:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code){

    // Careful here, any codes which are not specified
    // will be treated as 500

    if ( ! in_array($code,array(401,403,404,500))){
       return;
    }

    // assumes you have app/views/errors/401.blade.php, etc
    $view = "errors/$code";

    // add data that you want to pass to the view
    $data = array('code'=>$code);

    // switch statements provided in case you need to add
    // additional logic for specific error code.

    switch ($code) {
       case 401:
       return Response::view($view, $data, $code);

       case 403:
       return Response::view($view, $data, $code);

       case 404:
       return Response::view($view, $data, $code);

       case 500:
       return Response::view($view, $data, $code);

   }

});
```

The above snippet could be inserted in [app/start/global.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/start/global.php#L53) after the default Log::error handler, or better yet in the boot method of a custom [service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#service-providers).

EDIT: Updated so the handler only processes codes you specify.

Comment: Does this mean I should get rid of `App::missing(function($exception)` because your sample already handles 404 and also I noticed that it just gives a blank white page on any error if I have both.

Comment: Lastly how do I include the `ModelNotFoundException` here?

Comment: I would make another handler, example provided here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage

Comment: Oh, okay. That's what I did. I just though there is a way to handle everything in this one function. Thanks though :)

Comment: You may be able to, need to look into it.

Comment: You say "check the doc", but the doc mentions only report and render, so it could not really have led to your solution. But thanks for the pointer to App::error. Be nice if the doc mentioned it.

Comment: It seems, they have changed this logic in Laravel 5 - now errors are handled through report() and render() methods of App\Exceptions\Handler. I hope we still can catch all errors (fatal and shutdown) and exceptions there.